# Correct logic to cut out a slice of time for particular accounts

Tags: sql, sql-server, logical-operators

I can't get my head around the logic necessary for this action. I have data that runs month to date for multiple accounts. I want to specify that the output ignores certain accounts for a short range of time using SQL server 2016.

I want to **exclude** all data between 2017-09-14 14:30 and 2017-09-14 15:30 but only on accounts numbered 310722 310820 106758 310169 but I want to include data from those accounts (as well as all other accounts) for all other times.

I tried

```
WHERE 
([start time] NOT BETWEEN 2017-09-14 14:30 and 2017-09-14 15:30 AND Account NOT IN ( 310722, 310820, 106758, 310169,) )
```

but that cut out too much. The NOT and AND logic is messing me up. can anyone help?

**edit:**

Obviously my question is unclear. Apologies. I'm having a bit of trouble attaching sample data but below is my best effort.

```
Start Time           Type                Connected (secs) Account
13/09/2017 00:02:13 Normal operator call    20            141475
13/09/2017 00:02:15 Normal operator call    59            310523
13/09/2017 00:03:42 Normal operator call    83            833694
```

I want to include all the data that isn't on the specific accounts during the specific times. Maybe a Venn Diagram will help

[image: venn]

The blue area is the data **I don't want** everything else including the mentioned accounts at other times and all other accounts at the mentioned times I want to keep.

If anyone has more detailed suggestions to make this question less terrible I'd appreciate them. :)

Comment: https://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/    And somebody post the spaghetti dba link, too.

Comment: Could you please provide some sample data and output? It's unclear how the logic should work.

Answer (score 0):

How about a conditional where clause?

```
WHERE 
     [start time] < CASE WHEN Account in (310722,310820,106758,310169) THEN '2017-09-14 14:30' ELSE DATEADD(DAY,1,GETDATE()) END
  OR [start time] > CASE WHEN Account in (310722,310820,106758,310169) THEN '2017-09-14 15:30' ELSE '1900-01-01' END
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this

```
WHERE 
 NOT ([start time] BETWEEN '2017-09-14 14:30' and '2017-09-14 15:30' AND Account IN ( 310722, 310820, 106758, 310169) )
```

Comment: this wouldn't return rows for the other accounts though. OP didn't really specify if they wanted other accounts returned or not though so no harm yet :)

Comment: @scsimon you are right, it's unclear how OP want other accounts. I will update or delete this answer once OP clarify that.

Comment: sorry ericz i have updated the question hopefully it is a little clearer.

Comment: @tomdemaine my query should work for you, did you get chance try it?